# What does <R|T> in Observable<R|T> do in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Sometimes, I come across a code snippet similar to:

```
public getIdList():Observable<R|T>{
    return this.http.get(`http://v3.xxx.com:8000/api/onelist/idlist`)
      .map(this.handleSuccess)
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

or:

```
   public getIdList():Observable<T>{
    return this.http.get(`http://v3.xxx.com:8000/api/onelist/idlist`)
      .map(this.handleSuccess)
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

---

Can anyone explain what `<T>` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R|T` in the `Observable<R|T>` is a union type. It means that the type of the `Observable` is either `R` or `T`.

For `Observable<T>`, observable returns a data which type is `T`. This is called [**Generic type**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). For example `Observable<number>` says it returns a data which type is `number` and compiler can detect it and use that type for later parts.

**Generic Type**

```
interface A<T> {
   prop: T
}
```

and I use it

```
const obj1: A<number> = { prop: 4 }
```

This will set the type of `obj1` to `A<number>`. `A` is a generic type and uses it's type for the `prop` property. Setting the type to `number` just goes and put the passed `number` type for `prop`.

Answer (score 0):

Those are generic types.

The most explicit example is with firebase : when you request a collection, you do it with that :

```
this.firestore.collection<User>('users')
```

This means that in their file, the function is declared like this

```
collection<T>(collectionName: string) { ... }
```

R is just another generic type that you can use for unions.

It's like writing this :

```
private ID: string | number;
```

Your variable can then be a string, or a number. It's very useful for the intellisense, and is possible in Javascript because variables aren't typed.